# How to show top 3 fields from a column into horizontal row in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-concat

I have below table in MySQL,

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+------------------+-------------+--------+
| ServiceCode | ser_count | FirstName | LastName | PatientID | HealthCardNumber | DateOfBirth | Gender |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+------------------+-------------+--------+
| AAAA        |         1 | krishna   | Mangeter |         1 | ABC123           | 1982-02-02  | M      |
| BBBB        |         4 | Pinthna   | Paratter |         2 | KBC123           | 1981-02-02  | M      |
| IIII        |         2 | Pinthna   | Paratter |         2 | KBC123           | 1981-02-02  | M      |
| AAAA        |         1 | Pinthna   | Paratter |         2 | KBC123           | 1981-02-02  | M      |
| CCCC        |         1 | Pinthna   | Paratter |         2 | KBC123           | 1981-02-02  | M      |
| BBBB        |         3 | Pelahna   | Kumatter |         3 | SDF123           | 1984-02-02  | M      |
| AAAA        |         2 | Pelahna   | Kumatter |         3 | SDF123           | 1984-02-02  | M      |
| AAAA        |         1 | Pelahna   | Kumatter |         3 | SDF123           | 1984-02-02  | M      |
| BBBB        |         2 | Pelahna   | Kumatter |         3 | SDF123           | 1984-02-02  | M      |
| BBBB        |         2 | Pelahna   | Kumatter |         3 | SDF123           | 1984-02-02  | M      |
| GGGG        |         1 | Manshna   | Bituater |        14 | MKO123           | 1982-02-02  | M      |
| FFFF        |         1 | Manshna   | Bituater |        14 | MKO123           | 1982-02-02  | M      |
| IIII        |         3 | Manshna   | Bituater |        14 | MKO123           | 1982-02-02  | M      |
| GGGG        |         1 | Bahshna   | Vitueter |        15 | ZXS123           | 1982-02-02  | F      |
| IIII        |         1 | Krishhn   | Ishqeter |        16 | VGT123           | 1987-02-02  | M      |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+------------------+-------------+--------+
```

I want top three `ser_count` & `ServiceCode` for each `PatientID` from above table & want to show them horizontally as below. 
I tried with stored procedures in MySQL prompt,but it fails. Also I don't know stored procedures are working or not in iReport/jasperserver.

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+------------------+-------------+--------+------------------------+
| ServiceCode | ser_count | FirstName | LastName | PatientID | HealthCardNumber | DateOfBirth | Gender |Description             |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+------------------+-------------+--------+------------------------+
| AAAA        |         1 | krishna   | Mangeter |         1 | ABC123           | 1982-02-02  | M      |(1)AAAA                 |
| BBBB        |         4 | Pinthna   | Paratter |         2 | KBC123           | 1981-02-02  | M      |(4)BBBB (2)IIII (1)AAAA |
| BBBB        |         3 | Pelahna   | Kumatter |         3 | SDF123           | 1984-02-02  | M      |(3)BBBB (2)AAAA (2)BBBB |
| GGGG        |         1 | Manshna   | Bituater |        14 | MKO123           | 1982-02-02  | M      |(3)IIII (1)FFFF (1)GGGG |
| GGGG        |         1 | Bahshna   | Vitueter |        15 | ZXS123           | 1982-02-02  | F      |(2)GGGG                 |
| IIII        |         1 | Krishhn   | Ishqeter |        16 | VGT123           | 1987-02-02  | M      |(1)IIII                 |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+------------------+-------------+--------+------------------------+
```

Comment: Does the table change rapidly?

Comment: how is the table ordered? do you have an id? if you don't have an id to order by, i don't believe it's possible to answer your question

Comment: @zwang yes,this table changes dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ServiceCode, ser_count, FirstName, LastName, PatientID, 
       HealthCardNumber, DateOfBirth, Gender, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(IF(auto <= 3, code, '') ORDER BY ser_count DESC, servicecode SEPARATOR ' ') Description 
FROM (SELECT *, CONCAT('(', ser_count, ')', servicecode) code, 
             IF(@value=(@value:=PatientID), @auto:=@auto+1, @auto:=1) auto
      FROM table1, (SELECT @auto:=1, @value:=0 ) A
      ORDER BY PatientID, ser_count DESC, servicecode) as A 
GROUP BY PatientID;
```

Comment: but same query for ms-sql with modification,it gives some syntax errors as --
SELECT LastName, FirstName, sum(ser_count) as no_OU_services,sum(ou_month),       
       GROUP_CONCAT(IF(auto <= 3, code, '') ORDER BY ser_count DESC, servicecode SEPARATOR ' ') Description 
FROM (SELECT *, CONCAT('(', ser_count, ')', servicecode) code, 
IF(@value=(@value=PatientID)
begin @auto=@auto+1
end
else 
@auto=1 
end ) as auto
FROM contribute_2, (SELECT @auto=1, @value=0 ) A
ORDER BY PatientID, ser_count DESC, servicecode) as A 
GROUP BY PatientID;

can u tell me how should I go ?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 select * FROM your_table GROUP BY PatientID order by PatientID
```

look [**DEMO SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80391/1)

EDIT.

if he want top 3 then just add `limit` clause

```
     select * FROM Table1 GROUP BY PatientID order by PatientID  limit 3
```

[**HERE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80391/25)

**EDIT 3**

if you want to get 3 results for each PatientID then here you go

```
     SELECT ServiceCode, ser_count, FirstName,LastName,PatientID,HealthCardNumber,DateOfBirth,Gender
     FROM  (select ServiceCode, ser_count, FirstName,LastName,PatientID,HealthCardNumber,DateOfBirth,Gender,
           @num := if(@group = PatientID, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
           @group := PatientID as dude
    FROM   Table1
    ORDER BY PatientID, ServiceCode) as ord
    WHERE  row_number <= 3
```

look at [**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80391/32)

Comment: its not this what you are looking for ?

Comment: @SalmanA thanks for downvote , i edited my answer to get only top 3

Comment: Well, still does not return TOP 3 per Patient. Look at the sample input and output again.

Comment: @goodmood,thanks for your try,even if you don't give what I want ,but I got new things that is "SQLFiddle"